# Power series which is identically zero

Tags: complex-analysis

Im reading about complex power series in the book of Joseph Bak Donal J.Newman - Complex Analysis.

I have a question about the following statement :

> If a power series is equal to zero throughout a neighborhood of the origin it must be identically zero. For then all its derivatives at the origion and hence all the coefficients of the power series would equal 0. By the same reasoning if a power series were equal to zero throughout an interval containing the origin, it would be identically zero.

I get why, given a neighborhood of the origin which the series equal to zero in this neighborhood, all of the derivatives would also be 0 and hence the coefficients of the taylor series would vanish. But why is it true for just an interval? I assume that, for some reason, if a complex function is zero throughout an interval then its derivative would also be zero in that interval? its not intuitive for me because an interval is just a line and a neighborhood would be some sort of a disk which is 2 dimensional.

I'd appreciate an explanation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: All convergent power series are analytic; and analytic functions, by the Cauchy–Riemann equations, have the same derivative at a given point no matter what interval through that point is used to calculate the derivative.

Comment: One thing is unclear. Is the power series a power series of a complex variable (complex analytic), or of two real variables (two dimensional real analytic)? The function $f(x,y)=y^2$ is zero on the $x$-axis, yet the function is not identically $0$ in a neighborhood of the origin. If we are talking about a power series in a complex variable (complex analytic), then being $0$ on any line through the origin makes it identically $0$.

Comment: In any case, they do not contradict that a complex analytic power series that is $0$ on a line through the origin is identically $0$. They started out saying that a power series that is $0$ on a neighborhood of the origin is identically $0$, and related that to a power series that is $0$ on a neighborhood of the origin in one dimension, which happens to be a line.

Comment: You need a condition that the function is analytic in the neighborhood of the origin.  It is not enough for the function to have all its derivatives zero.  Example $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$

Comment: @herbsteinberg This is a power series

Comment: @FreeZe I presume that having a power series means the function is analytic in the neighborhood?

Comment: @herbsteinberg Yes, a power series in analytic in its region of convergence